# Using a constant string in URL using url Rewriting or Routes

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-rewriting

I have an Asp.Net website which should have a variable as a string in the url.

The content of the website changes depending on the year. the idea is to have this year in the url in a clean way.

```
http://localhost/YEAR/index.aspx
```

I have done this in MVC with routing, but i have no idea how to do it in asp.net.
I basically need just 1 route I guess. so all URL's will be as they were before (index.aspx, ...)

basically in stead of having `?year=2011` behind EVERY url in the website i'd like to have this value in the route.

How and what should i use for that? rewriting or routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here http://urlrewriter.net/

Download the assembly, add this as a reference in your project.

In web.config file in configSections element add this

```
<section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
```

create one more section

```
<rewriter>    
<rewrite url="http://localhost/(.*).aspx" to="http://localhost/index.aspx?year=$1"/>
</rewriter>
```

try to get the content you need with this http://localhost/2011.aspx

I Hope this helps